# WinForms DataGridView extended to be Multi-Threads safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Dears,
I am investigating multithreads programming. I would like to extend a DGV to be Multithread Safe. Code seems to be working fine but I am not sure about the use of "lock" statement:

```
public class MultiThreadsDataGridView:DataGridView
{

    public void UpdateCell(int Row, int Column, string Value) {

        lock (this)
        {
            Invoke(
                new Action(
                    () => Rows[Row].Cells[Column].Value = Value
                    )
                );
        }
    }


    public void AddRow(params object[] value) {

        lock(this){
            Invoke(
                new Action(
                    () => Rows.Add(value)
                    )
                );
        }
    }

}
```

Will the "lock", used in this way, be working as expected?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you expect. If you expect that only one single thread can enter the logic in either AddRow or UpdateCell then yes. If thread A starts to call UpdateCell and enters the lock and Thread B wants to AddRow, Thread B will wait/block at the lock statement at least until Thread A is finished.

Comment: My question is... Why? because windows controls are only supposed to be accessed by the thread that created them, this seems pointless

Comment: @rene that is how locking would work in that scenario, but that `Action` would likely fail when called from a different thread than the one handling the UI.

Comment: @Cleptus they are calling Invoke, I thought that guarantees the inner action is run on the UI thread. Has that changed or is there something I miss here?

Comment: @rene They should check the `InvokeRequired` property instead of locking on every action. The calls originated within the UI thread would perform poorly with that code

Comment: @Cleptus true that. But their code works as is and my comment correctly explains that. It **is** how locking works.

Comment: @rene - this is exactly what I need. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Caius Jard - The DGV shows the status of each thread. Each thread goes through different statuses and I want a complete view. To do that I use a DGV in which each thread updates its row. How would you do it otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolaDell'anna still look at the answer. It has additional guidance you need to apply.

Comment: *each thread updates its row* - each thread should signal to the UI thread that it's time to update row X. Only one thread (the thread that created the DGV) should be used to interact with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, it is not allowed accesing the UI elements withing other thread. That being said, it can be done using the `Control.Invoke` function or a `BackgroundWorker`.

Your code will work as expected indeed, but will perform poorly due to innecesary locking.

Check the official documentation for further information [How to make thread-safe calls to controls (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-6.0#example-use-the-invoke-method)

This is the example of the documentation using `Control.Invoke()` (I always found background workers a pain in the ass). They use `TextBox`, should be identical with `DataGridView`

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var threadParameters = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate { WriteTextSafe("This text was set safely."); });
    var thread2 = new System.Threading.Thread(threadParameters);
    thread2.Start();
}

public void WriteTextSafe(string text)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Call this same method but append THREAD2 to the text
        Action safeWrite = delegate { WriteTextSafe($"{text} (THREAD2)"); };
        textBox1.Invoke(safeWrite);
    }
    else
        textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: The OP is already calling Invoke

Comment: @rene Yeah, even when it was not needed, this code sample would perform better. If you are in a thread safe scenario it is very likely that unnecesary locking would be problematic later.